# RegEx expression, removing <div class...</div>

Tags: regex

Here is my String :

```
   "<img width="300" src="https://www.dvrgv.org/PhotosArticles/2017-07-25-VeloTaxi.jpg" alt="Manu dans le vélo-taxi, Brigitte aux commandes" /><br />
    <P>En juillet 2017, </P>
    <div class="powerpress_player" id="powerpress_player_9779"><!--[if lt IE 9]><script>document.createElement('audio');</script><![endif]-->
    <audio class="wp-audio-shortcode" id="audio-1097-1" preload="none" style="width: 100%;" controls="controls"><source type="audio/mpeg" src="https://www.dvrgv.org/_Reportages/2017-07-26-BrigiteVeloTaxi.mp3?_=1" /><a href="https://www.dvrgv.org/_Reportages/2017-07-26-BrigiteVeloTaxi.mp3">https://www.dvrgv.org/_Reportages/2017-07-26-BrigiteVeloTaxi.mp3</a></audio></div>dddf"
```

I'm looking for a regex expression, my goal:

```
"<img width="300" src="https://www.dvrgv.org/PhotosArticles/2017-07-25-VeloTaxi.jpg" alt="Manu dans le vélo-taxi, Brigitte aux commandes" /><br />
    <P>En juillet 2017, </P>dddf"
```

If anybody can help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `/(.*?)<div.*div>(.*)/gs` -> `\1\2`. [Test Online](https://regex101.com/r/TPg6dZ/1)

Answer (score 0):

A more strict and less error prone regex than the answer of abskmj is the following:

```
preg_replace("/(.*?)<div class=\".*?\/div>(.*)/s","$1$2",$your_text);
```

which uses a non-greedy modifier ( .*? instead of .* ) .If you use a greedy modifier .* and in your text there is somewhere a closing div tag bellow dddf for example,then the regex will replace everything until the last closing div it finds which you probably don't want.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution ;-)

I must manage line breaks with `[\s\S]` !

```
<div class="powerpress_player" \b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)\/div>
```